# Upgrading from 4.2.6 to 4.6.8

Tags: drupal, upgrade

we've been running CiviCRM 4.2.6 for a number of years now on Drual 6 and I've finally got round to upgrading. Has anyone here gone from 4.2 to 4.6? Any gotchas that you hit?

I've run the upgrade on our test Drupal 6 site and once MySQL permissions around triggers were sorted the upgrade ran through fine.

I'm keen to hear other peoples experiences.

Em

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM 4.6 officially supports direct upgrades from versions as far back as 4.0.8, so you fall within that window.

If you've already done a trial run on your test site and everything checks out, I'd say you're good to go. Back up your live site just prior to running the upgrade.

If the core upgrade works fine, then the biggest concern about things that could go wrong is with integrations - if your site has any custom code, modules or extensions related to Civi, be sure to review them to ensure they still work with the latest version. I would do thorough testing on your test site first.

Comment: Thanks both for your answers. Good to know if the upgrade runs through things are generally fine. I'll definitely check integrations with Drupal. We do have some custom stuff. And I'll get the users to test, test, test.

Answer (score 1):

Been involved in a few upgrades from 4.2 to 4.6 and generally they work fine. If you've got it running through as Coleman has said your in a pretty good position. Sometimes we'll got 4.2 to 4.4 then up to 4.5 or 4.6 to reduce the risk of something going wrong. As you've mentioned there are now mysql triggers and functions that CiviCRM relies on and this can sometimes trip things up. Back everything up before you do it on your production environment.